# AJAX Form Issues with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms, asynchronous

I'm sure this question has been asked before in a different context but I'm still so stuck with figuring out AJAX Rails and, I guess, Rails in general (kinda makes me wonder if I should just go back to PHP...).  Well anyways I have this form that I want to AJAXify.

This is the "list" view which is part of the "subject" controller

```
<h1>Listing Subjects</h1>

<ul id="subject_list">

    <% @subjects.each do |c| %>
    <li><%= link_to c.name, :action => 'show', :id => c.id %></li>
    <% end %>

</ul>

<p id="add_link"><%= link_to_function("Add a Subject",
"Element.remove('add_link'); Element.show('add_subject')")%></p>

<div id="add_subject" style="display:none;">

<%= form_tag(:action => 'create') do%>
    Name: <%= text_field "subject", "name" %>
    <%= submit_tag 'Add' %>
<% end %>

</div>
```

Code for my "subject" controller

```
class SubjectController < ApplicationController

  def list
    @subjects = User.find(:all)
  end

  def show
    @subject = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @subject = User.new(params[:subject])
    if @subject.save
        render :partial => 'subject', :object => @subject
    end
  end

end
```

My "subject" partial

```
<li id="subject_<%= subject.id %>">
<%= link_to subject.name, :action => 'show', :id => subject.id %>
</li>
```

And the User is just a simple model I made that contains two columns "name" and "email".

How this code currently works is that when you click "Add", the textfield input is revealed.  When you type something in the input and submit it, the "_show" partial is rendered in the create link.  I was following a Rails 2.0 tutorial but I have 3.0 and I've read through some tutorials and they all mention ":remote => true" and jquery_ujs.js but I have no idea how to apply them to a "form_tag" rather than "form_for" Rails helper.

Basically I want to asynchronously add the element to the bottom of the list without a page load.  I've really tried to understand absolutely all of the tutorials I could find but I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you'd better use some Unobtrusive JavaScript to tell to your app
and browser what exactly you want to render and how.
You want too much from simple `render :partial => 'subject', :object => @subject` line of code.

Here's my snippet that may be helpful to you.

```
# in the view (:remote => true for form_tag is not problem at all)
<%= form_tag({:controller => :products, :action => :empty_cart }, {:id => 'empty_cart', :remote => true}) do %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Clear' %>
<% end %>

# in the controller (note that format.js section in the respond_to block)
def empty_cart
  ...
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to :root, :notice => 'Your cart is empty now' } # in the case of disabled JS support
    format.js   { render :js => "$('#empty_cart').fadeOut()" } # or you can place js code in the empty_cart.js.erb file and specify format.js here without the block 
  end
end
```

Check [this](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/using-unobtrusive-javascript-and-ajax-with-rails-3/) article if I'm not clear enough.